# Loading other different viewController with parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my viewController2 I have different UIView's, and let's say that when I load my viewController2 from viewController3 I need to show only UIView2. Is it possible to do that?

viewController2, has many forms. For example, after clicking the button on form1 it would hide form1 and show form2 and so on. Now, the problem is if I load my viewController2 from viewController3 is it possible to just show form2 and not form1?

Here's how I load my viewController2:

```
[APP_DELEGATE setUIBlockingEnabled:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.rootViewController = nil;
appDelegate.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.rootViewController;
appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
RegistrationViewController *controller = [[RegistrationViewController alloc]init];
[appDelegate.rootViewController moveToViewController:controller];
```

//viewController2

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *rectHolder1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *rectHolder2;
```

rectHolder1 and rectHolder2 has different subviews, and upon page load I am showing rectHolder1 and rectHolder2 is not visible. When the user clicks on the rectHolder1's button it would hide rectHolder1 and show rectHolder2. Now how can I directly show rectHolder2 if I am loading viewController2 from another viewController

Comment: can't understand exactly what you want! be more specific !

Comment: Edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Try to post some screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: How you are loading View 2 from View 3

Comment: Edited my question again. Hopefully you'll get what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to manage this kind of stuff in `viewWillAppear` of your `viewController2`. Set some flag when you come from `VC3 to VC2` so that you can differentiate that you are coming from VC3 or not! If your flag is true(I mean you are coming from VC3) then show your desired view else show other content that you want to show! If you are going forward means you have pushing `VC2` from `VC3`(which less possible as per naming of viewcontrollers) then you can use `prepareforsegue` to set flag! If you are popping to `VC2` from `VC3` then you can use `delegate and protocol` or `NSUserDefaults` for store or set the flag!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can choose to hide the views(let say firstView) you don't want to display by simply hiding that view(firstView) or if your other view's(let say secondView) constraint are been set with respect to the view(firstView) which you want to hide, then you may change the height of view(firstView) to zero.

In this way you will be able to hide the views you want to hide. You just need to decide which view you need to hide and then change the constraint or hide the view when going to that viewController.